# Unable to configure second level cache of hibernate-ehcache-4.3.5.Final.jar in Hibernate 5.1.0.Final

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I'm trying to achieve second level cache in my Java EE project using Hibernate. My Hibernate version is 5.1.0.Final. I've created a table `employee` in my MySQL database. I've included `hibernate-ehcache-4.3.5.Final.jar` in my project, but it's throwing `Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]` error. Here is the `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/intu</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

     <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
     <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>  
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>  



 <property name="show_sql">false</property>
 <property name="format_sql">true</property>
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
 <mapping class="com.dom.Employee"/>  

 </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

My `Employee` class:

```
package com.intu;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

 import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
 import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

 @Entity
 @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
 @Table(name = "employee")
 public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;


    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String name, float salary) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
         return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }  

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 
}
```

My Code:

```
package com.test;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import com.intu.Employee;
import com.util.HibernateUtil;

public class Ehcache {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString());
        SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session1=factory.openSession();  
        Employee emp1=(Employee)session1.load(Employee.class,121);  
        System.out.println(emp1.getId()+" "+emp1.getName());  
        session1.close();  

        Session session2=factory.openSession();  
        Employee emp2=(Employee)session2.load(Employee.class,121);  
        System.out.println(emp2.getId()+" "+emp2.getName());  
        session2.close();   
    }
}
```

The error is

```
eb 23, 2016 3:10:49 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
 Feb 23, 2016 3:10:49 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 23, 2016 3:10:49 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Initial SessionFactory creation  failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested  service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:20)
at com.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:7)
at com.test.Ehcache.main(Ehcache.java:14)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create   requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
at   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:663)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:655)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at com.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
... 2 more
 Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate    RegionFactory [net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory]
at   org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactor  yInitiator.java:84)
at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactor  yInitiator.java:29)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
```

I'm not sure what exactly is missing. What should be added more to get it working?

Comment: it is better not to use hibernate-ehcache, it is depicted: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12441, instead go for hibernate-jcache

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You are using incompatible versions of EhCache and Hibernate, that leads to initialization issues.** if you are using Hibernate 5.1, better to use the corresponding ehcache version to go with it:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: ,You're right. Both versions should be same. Also I didn't had log4j JAR, after that it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

--Add the below line at hibernate.cfg.xml

`<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.EhcacheRegionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</property>`

The above one would solve the issue.